# Branch of a square root

Tags: complex-analysis

Denote $\sqrt{}$ a branch of a square root. I want to show that the identity $\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{z}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{z}}$ can be false, but I don't find a counterexample.

Does anyone know a counterexample for this identity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z=-1$. Then $\sqrt{\tfrac{1}{-1}}=\sqrt{-1}=i$, but $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{-1}}=\tfrac{1}{i}=-i$